# Performance of multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, python-multiprocessing

I've created a quite simple script that works with multiprocessing and SQL. The aim of this exercise is to obtain the lowest time of execution :

```
def Query(Query):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("DB.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()  
    cur.execute(Query)
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn = sqlite3.connect("DB.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    start = time.time()
    curOperations.execute(QUERY)
    curOperations.execute(QUERY)
    curOperations.execute(QUERY)
    end = time.time()
    TIME1 = end - start
    cur.execute('PRAGMA journal_mode=wal')
    conn.commit()

    start = time.time()
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    pool.imap(Query,[QUERY, QUERY, QUERY])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    end = time.time()
    TIME2 = end - start
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

The average result for TIME1 after 20 executions is 13.43 and for TIME2, 10.39.

Shouldn't it be lower than that ?! am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: `13.43 / 3 = 4.48 sec` and `10.39 / 2 = 5.2 sec` is pretty comparable taking into consideration how much overhead making new process has. I'd say it's performing better than I'd expect.

Comment: I do not understand why are you dividing by 2 in the multiprocessing case

Comment: 3 tasks, 2 processes, which means that one of them will have to do 2 jobs sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

For my answer, I will *assume* that your query only *reads* things from the database.

Before you try to make something faster, you need to know *what exactly* is preventing the process from being faster.
Not all speed problems are amendable to improvement by multiprocessing!

So what you really need to do is *profile* the application to see where it spends its time.

Since SQLite does caching of queries, I would suggest timing each execution of the query in the single process separately.
I would suspect that the first query takes longer than the following ones.

Also consider the *overhead* in the multiprocessing case. The query has to be pickled and sent to the worker process via IPC. Then each worker has to create a connection and cursor and close them afterwards. In a real world situation, your query function would have done something with the data, e.g. return it to the master process which also requires pickling it and sending it via IPC.

Since all workers access the same database, at some point the reading from the database will become the bottleneck.

If you query *modifies* the database, access will be serialized anyway to prevent coruption.

Comment: And what if I do only one connection intstead of doing one connection par query

Comment: That would reduce the overhead, but it is still not a given that it would be faster. Don't guess, *measure*.